# Deploy reactjs for upload into vps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a `ReactJS` project, I used `npm run build` to deploy static, now I want to upload to my `vps`, it working good, but after I go to `mysite.com/Login` if I reload page (refresh) it give me `404 error`.

**package.json**

```
  "name": "homer",
  "homepage": ".",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
```

> 404 Not Found The resource requested could not be found on this
> server!

what is the problem?

I just want when I refresh page, it show page correctly.

*I tried to set `domain` on `homepage` in package.json but nothing changed.*

Comment: do you have `_redirects` file?

Comment: You need this: https://gist.github.com/alexsasharegan/173878f9d67055bfef63449fa7136042 (provided your server uses Apache)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Comment: @demkovych no what is this?

Comment: @ChrisG I'm using LiteSpeed

Comment: add _redirects file into your public folder with this content: `/*    /index.html   200`

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313736/htaccess-doesnt-work-in-litespeed

Comment: @demkovych nothing changed :/